# Comentários em classes causam lentidão no Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eu tenho um projeto antigo, cujo tamanho é 225Mb, onde a maioria das classes tem o corpo todo comentado. No passado eu não usava versionamento de código na minha empresa e o versionamento era feito no próprio código, comentando uma linha e escrevendo a alteração na linha abaixo. Exemplo:

==> 2019-07-09 o código era:

```
System.out.println ("Hello World 1");
```

==> 2019-07-10 o código era:

```
//System.out.println("Olá Mundo 1 ");
System.out.println ("Hello World 2");
```

==> 2019-07-11 o código era:

```
//System.out.println("Olá Mundo 1 ");
//System.out.println ("Hello World 2");
System.out.println ("Hello World 3");
```

Agora imagine isso para mais de 2000 classes, onde existem vários blocos grandes de código comentado.

Todas essas classes podem causar lentidão no Eclipse?

Por que quando abro este projeto o Eclipse fica muito lento?

Comment: Sim, absolutamente, o eclispe é um IDE e corre verificações analisando o texto e quanto maior o texto maior o tempo de execução e por isso aparece a lentidão a que se refere.
Estão a ser feitas operações no fundo, o que faz com que o programa de edição fique lento.

Comment: Há algum profile do eclipse onde seja possível apresentar esses gargalos ?

Comment: @IgorMoisés como não é uma questão do programa sendo desenvolvido, você precisa usar um `profiler` direto no Eclipse. Talvez o VisualVM consiga pegar, mas não sei o quão útil será para você, nem se a informação estará prontamente legível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vou afirmar categoricamente, mas não causa nada muito significativo, pelo menos deveria ser algo muito pequeno e imperceptível.

Eu sei que o Eclipse faz muitas análises enquanto você está codificando e isso tem um custo, quanto mais texto para analisar mais lento fica, mas não é para mudar muita coisa, o grosso do tempo gasto na análise é feita em coisas muito mais relevantes, o casso dos comentários só gastará tempo no *scanner* e imagino ter otimizações para evitar repetição onde não deve, então não deve se preocupar com isso.

Eu passaria os dados de versionamento para outro lugar e retirá-los pra limpar o código com coisas que não deveriam estar aí, deve dar um ligeiro ganho (bem ligeiro mesmo, não sei se perceberá) mas o motivo para fazer isto não deve ser a performance.

Códigos antigos não deveriam ficar na base de código oficial, tire isto também.

O Eclipse é lento e isto é perceptível quanto mais código tem. O estrago maior é analisando o código em si e não os comentários. O Eclipse tem uma arquitetura ruim e ultrapassada, é famoso por ser lento e dá má fama ao Java que um dia já foi lento mas hoje não é mais. A maior parte das lentidões encontradas em programas Java é culpa do programa e não do Java, é muita gente com mentalidade de "código enterprise" enfiando um monte de penduricalhos desnecessários em nome de "boas práticas" que elas não entendem.

Comment: A situação é que esse código legado já foi colocado num sistema de versionamento. O que acontece é que ele subiu do jeito que esta. Com grandes blocos de código comentado dentro das inúmeras classes. Quais outras ferramentas para desenvolvimento em java tem-se atualmente ?

Comment: @IgorMoisés apaga e ignora

Comment: JetBrains IntelliJ

Comment: Obrigado nobres colegas! Irei propor as mudanças!

Comment: Lembrando que o IntelliJ é pago, e a versão community não provê diversas features